# Reordering an matrix in numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have an arbitrary matrix that is 3x3 where the

```
           A  B  C
       A [[0, 1, 0],
       B [1, 0, 1],
       C [0, 1, 0]]
```

And I have a list `labels = [0,1,0]` that corresponds to each column of the matrix.
For example 0 would correspond to column 1, 1 would correspond to column 2, so on..
I want to reorder the matrix such that it is ordered by in ascending order of the labels.

Column 1 is A, Column 2 is B, and Column 3 is C.
Row 1 is A, Row 2 is B, and Row 3 is C.
The order shouldn't mess with what each row/column is.

So my expected matrix output matrix will be:

```
          C  A  B
      C [[0, 0, 1],
      A [0, 0, 1],
      B [1, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: I can't quite understand what you want. What are A, B and C all about? There are 4 labels, I was expecting 4 columns (maybe?) in the output. To put it another way, how exactly does the first `0` in `labels` get interpreted?

Comment: Sorry i'm having a bit trouble explaining. Basically I want the order to be based on the labels. So if the label is 0 it should be grouped first with every column that is 0-labeled. A corresponds to column 1 and row 1, B corresponds to column 2 and row 2, and C corresponds to column 3 and row 3. The first matrix is ordered by A,B,C the output matrix is ordered by C,A,B based on the labels list.

Comment: Okay, the first label is `0`. So I think that means you go to your array and select the column with index `0`, i.e. `[0, 1, 0]`. What happens next? How does this determine what appears in the output?

Comment: Sorry I just edited by post with column and row labels and the labels list which was wrong before. Basically since the first element and third element of the labels list is 0 they must be grouped first. They correspond with A and C respectively, it doesnt matter which order A and C is but they have to be grouped before columns/rows that have a 1 label (for example B)

Comment: That makes sense... but in the input `A` is `[0, 1, 0]` (as is `C`), but in the output they seem to be `[0, 0, 1]`. Is that right? If so, I guess they have been sorted. But then `B` is ordered 'backwards'... so then I'm confused again.

Comment: The [0][0] position denotes how far A is from A, which is 0 if you look at the first matrix. The position [0][1] is how Far A is from B which is 1. When you switch the order the differences in lengths should be the same still. Thats why the matrix is symmetric. sorry for the confusion, terrible at explaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me some time to understand, but I think I know what you want to do now.

```
>>> x = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
>>> labels = [0, 1, 0]
>>> order = np.argsort(labels) # Find a sorted order of the given labels
>>> x[order][:, order] # Sort the rows and then the columns
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I was looking for.